# Migrate postgresql schema AWS RDS

Tags: postgresql, database-migration, amazon-rds

Ok, I'm a mobile developer trying to learn backend development.

I have two AWS RDS instances running postgresql. One for development and one for production.

The scenario is that the development data base is operated on. Create tables, add postgis, new relationships, what ever.

Now, I want to go put all those schema changes into the production database. Obviously I don't want to migrate development data to production, just the schema and db changes.

What do I do?

Answer (score 2):

You can dump schema only:

```
pg_dump -s databasename > your_schema.sql
```

Then you restore the dumped schema from `your_schema.sql` by running on the production sever:

```
psql < your_schema.sql
```

Use user/pass options as needed.

Comment: Thank you Pablo. Any way to do this with out `psql`?